cxf-codegen-plugin 4 unable to generate setter for Collections
Is there any solution for generating setter for Collections with the latest cxf-codegen-plugin ?
Steps Tried

jdk: 21
cxf-codegen-plugin: 4.0.3
net.java.dev.vcc.thirdparty:collection-setter-injector:0.5.0-1
extraargs > -xjc-Xcollection-setter-injector

Previous outcome
The same used to work fine with

jdk 8 or 11
cxf-codegen-plugin: 2.6.1
net.java.dev.vcc.thirdparty:collection-setter-injector:0.5.0-1
extraargs > -xjc-Xcollection-setter-injector

Error received:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
'com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter
com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.getNameConverter()'

One of the solution that was suggested is to fork and makes changes to a 3rd party plugin to generate setters for Collections
Related articles

Maven CXF wsdl2java list setter not generated
https://github.com/bjornvester/wsdl2java-gradle-plugin/issues/26 : Here the suggestion is to fork the 3rd party code and make changes to the package to make it work.

Any inputs or suggestion is truly appreciated.
